# Strange behavior of the timezones with `unnest()`

Tags: r, timezone, tidyr, lubridate, unnest

The behavior of `unnest()` regarding the timezones seems strange to me.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Sys.getenv("TZ")
#[1] "Europe/Paris"

reprex_unnest <- tribble(
  ~datetime, ~locale,
  "2018-03-08 01:00:00",   "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
  "2018-03-08 01:00:00",   "Europe/Kiev",
  "2018-03-08 01:00:00",   "UTC"
) %>%
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime, tz = "UTC")
         , datetime_locale = map2(datetime, locale, ~ with_tz(.x, tzone = .y) ))%>%
  unnest(datetime_locale) %>% 
  mutate(tz_datetime = tz(datetime)
         , tz_datetime_locale = tz(datetime_locale))

reprex_unnest

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   datetime            locale        datetime_locale     tz_datetime tz_datetime_locale
#   <dttm>              <chr>         <dttm>              <chr>       <chr>            
# 1 2018-03-08 01:00:00 America/Arge… 2018-03-08 01:00:00 UTC         UTC
# 2 2018-03-08 01:00:00 Europe/Kiev   2018-03-08 01:00:00 UTC         UTC
# 3 2018-03-08 01:00:00 UTC           2018-03-08 01:00:00 UTC         UTC
```

It seems `with_tz` wasn't applied

```
reprex_no_unnest <- tribble(
  ~datetime, ~locale,
  "2018-03-08 01:00:00",   "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
  "2018-03-08 01:00:00",   "Europe/Kiev",
  "2018-03-08 01:00:00",   "UTC"
) %>%
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime, tz = "UTC")) %>% 
  mutate(datetime_locale = map2(datetime, locale, ~ with_tz(.x, tzone = .y) ))

str(reprex_no_unnest)

# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ datetime       : POSIXct, format: "2018-03-08 01:00:00" ...
#  $ locale         : chr  "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires" "Europe/Kiev" "UTC"
#  $ datetime_locale:List of 3
#   ..$ : POSIXct, format: "2018-03-07 22:00:00"
#   ..$ : POSIXct, format: "2018-03-08 03:00:00"
#   ..$ : POSIXct, format: "2018-03-08 01:00:00"
```

But behind the scenes, `with_tz` actually is applied and returns the expected result.

I guess the issue boils down to this

```
tz(reprex$datetime_locale[1])
#[1] "UTC"
tz(reprex$datetime_locale[[1]])
#[1] "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
tz(reprex$datetime_locale[[2]])
#[1] "Europe/Kiev"
```

The `tz` of the list column is actually UTC, and I guess it takes priority over the `tz` of each element.

It this an expected `R` behavior or did I miss anything ?
What should I do to obtain the expected result ?

Comment: I first opened an issue on the github repo but after sleeping on it, I felt it may be more useful and appropriate to post on stack overflow.
Feel free to tell me if there is a specific etiquette.

Comment: It is better to keep the different time zone objects in the list